# How to read pdf , doc and excel in browser

Tags: javascript, file, browser, froala

I am working on a Froala plugin that will allow user to upload excel , doc and pdfs and import text from it and insert it in editor.

I need to design a functionality which will behave like as if I opened the file, selected all the text, copy it and paste it in Editor.

I can open a file in browser using FileReader but the content from it is encoded and programmatically pasting it in Editor is not working.

Anyone have any idea how to do it ?

I want to build this using raw browser APIs rather than pdf.js and other libs to parse the content of excel and doc files.

Comment: So you're saying that you want to make your own pdf.js?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.